# How to enable video playing in full screen in my Android Webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I tried to enable graphics acceleration but didn't worked for me
Here is my code
[Click here to see](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12-D8RdzIwJRsh-SdmJRST1HvrY3AQs0s/view?usp=sharing)
I am getting this error too   [click here too see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNWZ1.jpg)

Please help me I am stuck
Can someone help me with the code

Comment: Check this article(note that article is not mine all rights and credits belongs to its author):https://medium.com/@oliverdamjan2013/fullscreen-youtube-video-in-webview-android-21f1c778cf56

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should use `VideoView` for this purpose. It allows to view videos from some url in fullscreen.

First, create a player activity xml file with `VideoView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <VideoView android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` for your `PlayerActivity` set `screenOrientation` attribute to `landscape`:

```
<activity android:name=".PlayerActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

Finally, in your `PlayerActivity.kt` set fullscreen flags and load your video url (or local file - check [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView)):

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // Fullscreen mode
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player)

    // Load your video file
    video_view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(intent.getStringExtra(URL_TO_VIEW)))
    video_view.setMediaController(MediaController(this))
    video_view.requestFocus(0)
    video_view.start()
}
```

Or if you write in Java, in your `PlayerActivity.java`:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Fullscreen mode
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

        // Load your video file
        VideoView videoView = findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra(URL_TO_VIEW)));
        videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        videoView.requestFocus(0);
        videoView.start();
    }
```

Comment: I am using Java sir not Kotlin is this code will work